# How shoud my AP or network be configured?

Tags: access-point

I am triying to build rt5370 ap mode.
The build is success, but the network has some problems.

When I execute hostapd, the AP seemed to operate.

```
    / # hostapd -dd etc/hostapd-test.conf &
    / # interface count = 1 argc(3) optind(2)
    random: Trying to read entropy from /dev/random
    Configuration file: etc/hostapd-test.conf
    nl80211: Could not add multicast membership for vendor events: -2 (No such file or directory)
    rfkill: Cannot open RFKILL control device
    nl80211: RFKILL status not available
    nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:1
    nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:5
    nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:2
    nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:4
    nl80211: Using driver-based off-channel TX
    nl80211: interface ra0 in phy phy0
    nl80211: Set mode ifindex 2 iftype 3 (AP)
    nl80211: Setup AP(ra0) - device_ap_sme=0 use_monitor=1
    nl80211: Create interface iftype 6 (MONITOR)
    Failed to create interface mon.ra0: -95 (Operation not supported)
    nl80211: Driver does not support monitor interface type - try to run without it
    nl80211: Enable Probe Request reporting nl_preq=0x91808
    nl80211: Register frame type=0x40 nl_handle=0x91808 match=
    [ 1469.036182] 80211> CFG80211_OpsMgmtFrameRegister ==>
    [ 1469.041073] frame_type = 40, req = 1
    [ 1469.044595] pAd->Cfg80211RegisterProbeReqFrame=1[1]
    [ 1469.517521] NICLoadFirmware: We need to load firmware
    [ 1469.883720] RTUSBVenderReset
    [ 1469.974305]  re-init bands...
    [ 1470.979834] 80211> re-init bands...
    [ 1470.983192] 80211> RFICType = 1
    [ 1470.986378] 80211> Number of channel = 44
    [ 1470.993204] 80211> Number of rate = 12
    [ 1470.996899] 80211> CurTxPower = 0 dBm
    [ 1471.000424] 80211> TxStream = 1
    [ 1471.009952] crda> CFG80211_RegRuleApply ==>
    [ 1471.018000] crda> reset chan/power for 2.4GHz
    [ 1471.022272] Chan 001:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0
    [ 1471.027198] Chan 002:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0
    [ 1471.032078] Chan 003:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0
    [ 1471.037113] Chan 004:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0
    [ 1471.041971] Chan 005:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0
    [ 1471.046927] Chan 006:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0
    [ 1471.051849] Chan 007:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0
    [ 1471.056796] Chan 008:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0
    [ 1471.061731] Chan 009:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0
    [ 1471.066675] Chan 010:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0
    [ 1471.071605] Chan 011:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0
    [ 1471.076556] Chan 012:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0
    [ 1471.081490] Chan 013:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0
    [ 1471.086435] Chan 014:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0
    [ 1471.108832] crda> Number of channels = 14
    [ 1471.114585] 0x1300 = 00073200
    nl80211: error: 4379
    nl80211: Add own interface ifindex 2
    nl80211: if_indices[16]: 2
    nl80211: Add own interface ifindex 3
    nl80211: if_indices[16]: 2 3
    nl80211: Adding interface ra0 into bridge br0
    [ 1471.196199] device ra0 entered promiscuous mode
    phy: phy0
    BSS count 1, BSSID mask 00:00:00:00:00:00 (0 bits)
    nl80211: Regulatory information - country=00
    nl80211: 2402-2472 @ 40 MHz 20 mBm
    nl80211: 2457-2482 @ 20 MHz 20 mBm (no IR)
    nl80211: 2474-2494 @ 20 MHz 20 mBm (no OFDM) (no IR)
    nl80211: 5170-5250 @ 40 MHz 20 mBm (no IR)
    nl80211: 5735-5835 @ 40 MHz 20 mBm (no IR)
    nl80211: Added 802.11b mode based on 802.11g information
    Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=1 freq=2412 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
    Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=2 freq=2417 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
    Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=3 freq=2422 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
    Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=4 freq=2427 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
    Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=5 freq=2432 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
    Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=6 freq=2437 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
    Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=7 freq=2442 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
    Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=8 freq=2447 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
    Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=9 freq=2452 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
    Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=10 freq=2457 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
    Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=11 freq=2462 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
    Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=1 freq=2412 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
    Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=2 freq=2417 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
    Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=3 freq=2422 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
    Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=4 freq=2427 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
    Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=5 freq=2432 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
    Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=6 freq=2437 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
    Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=7 freq=2442 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
    Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=8 freq=2447 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
    Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=9 freq=2452 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
    Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=10 freq=2457 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
    Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=11 freq=2462 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
    Completing interface initialization
    Mode: IEEE 802.11g  Channel: 10  Frequency: 2457 MHz
    DFS 0 channels required radar detection
    nl80211: Set freq 2457 (ht_enabled=0, vht_enabled=0, bandwidth=20 MHz, cf1=2457 MHz, cf2=0 MHz)
    [ 1471.436434] 80211> New BW = 1
    [ 1471.439241] 80211> HT Disable = 1
    RATE[0] rate=10 flags=0x1
    RATE[1] rate=20 flags=0x1
    RATE[2] rate=55 flags=0x1
    RATE[3] rate=110 flags=0x1
    RATE[4] rate=60 flags=0x0
    RATE[5] rate=90 flags=0x0
    RATE[6] rate=120 flags=0x0
    RATE[7] rate=180 flags=0x0
    RATE[8] rate=240 flags=0x0
    RATE[9] rate=360 flags=0x0
    RATE[10] rate=480 flags=0x0
    RATE[11] rate=540 flags=0x0
    hostapd_setup_bss(hapd=0x90dd0 (ra0), first=1)
    ra0: Flushing old station entries
    nl80211: flush -> DEL_STATION ra0 (all)
    ra0: Deauthenticate all stations
    [ 1471.497384] Can't find pEntry in ApStaDel
    nl80211: sta_remove -> DEL_STATION ra0 ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff --> 0 (Success)
    wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=2 (ra0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=0 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
    [ 1471.520011] 80211> CFG80211_OpsKeyDel ==>
    [ 1471.526820] 80211> KeyDel isPairwise 0
    [ 1471.530739] 80211> AP Key Del
    wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=2 (ra0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=1 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
    [ 1471.552923] 80211> CFG80211_OpsKeyDel ==>
    [ 1471.557994] 80211> KeyDel isPairwise 0
    [ 1471.561711] 80211> AP Key Del
    wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=2 (ra0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=2 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
    [ 1471.580520] 80211> CFG80211_OpsKeyDel ==>
    [ 1471.584563] 80211> KeyDel isPairwise 0
    [ 1471.588445] 80211> AP Key Del
    wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=2 (ra0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=3 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
    [ 1471.611132] 80211> CFG80211_OpsKeyDel ==>
    [ 1471.618957] 80211> KeyDel isPairwise 0
    [ 1471.622816] 80211> AP Key Del
    Using interface ra0 with hwaddr 7c:dd:90:00:00:00 and ssid "test"
    nl80211: Set beacon (beacon_set=0)
    nl80211: Beacon head - hexdump(len=55): 80 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff 7c dd 90 76 24 5b 7c dd 90 76 24 5b 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 64 00 01 04 00 04 74 65 73 74 01 08 82 84 8b 96 0c 12 18 24 03 01 0a
    nl80211: Beacon tail - hexdump(len=9): 2a 01 04 32 04 30 48 60 6c
    nl80211: ifindex=2
    nl80211: beacon_int=100
    nl80211: dtim_period=2
    nl80211: ssid - hexdump_ascii(len=4):
         74 65 73 74                                       test
    nl80211: hidden SSID not in use
    nl80211: privacy=0
    nl80211: auth_algs=0x3
    nl80211: wpa_version=0x0
    nl80211: key_mgmt_suites=0x2
    nl80211: pairwise_ciphers=0x1
    nl80211: group_cipher=0x1
    [ 1471.713768] YF Debug: SSID: test, 4
    [ 1471.717164] AP BSSID 7c:dd:90:00:00:00
    [ 1471.998984] YF DEBUG: RTUSBBssBeaconInit
    [ 1472.011997] YF DEBUG: Beacon Len 64
    [ 1472.016367] YF DEBUG: Beacon Interval 100
    [ 1472.025984] RTUSBBulkReceive!
    nl80211: Set ra0 operstate 0->1 (UP)
    netlink: Operstate: ifindex=2 linkmode=-1 (no change), operstate=6 (IF_OPER_UP)
    Failed to set TX queue parameters for queue 0.
    Failed to set TX queue parameters for queue 1.
    Failed to set TX queue parameters for queue 2.
    Failed to set TX queue parameters for queue 3.
    ra0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->ENABLED
    ra0: AP-ENABLED
    ra0: Setup of interface done.
    ctrl_iface not configured!
    RTM_NEWLINK: ifi_index=2 ifname=ra0 operstate=0 linkmode=0 ifi_flags=0x11043 ([UP][RUNNING][LOWER_UP])
    RTM_NEWLINK: ifi_index=3 ifname=br0 operstate=2 linkmode=0 ifi_flags=0x1002 ()
    nl80211: Ignore interface down event since interface br0 is up
    RTM_NEWLINK: ifi_index=3 ifname=br0 operstate=2 linkmode=0 ifi_flags=0x1002 ()
    nl80211: Ignore interface down event since interface br0 is up
    RTM_NEWLINK: ifi_index=2 ifname=ra0 master=3 operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x11043 ([UP][RUNNING][LOWER_UP])
    nl80211: Add ifindex 3 for bridge br0
    nl80211: Add own interface ifindex 3
    nl80211: ifindex 3 already in the list
    RTM_NEWLINK: ifi_index=2 ifname=ra0 operstate=0 linkmode=0 master=3 ifi_flags=0x11043 ([UP][RUNNING][LOWER_UP])
    RTM_NEWLINK: ifi_index=2 ifname=ra0 master=3 operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x11043 ([UP][RUNNING][LOWER_UP])
    nl80211: Add ifindex 3 for bridge br0
    nl80211: Add own interface ifindex 3
    nl80211: ifindex 3 already in the list
    RTM_NEWLINK: ifi_index=2 ifname=ra0 master=3 operstate=6 ifi_flags=0x11043 ([UP][RUNNING][LOWER_UP])
    nl80211: Add ifindex 3 for bridge br0
    nl80211: Add own interface ifindex 3
    nl80211: ifindex 3 already in the list
    RTM_NEWLINK: ifi_index=2 ifname=ra0 operstate=6 linkmode=0 master=3 ifi_flags=0x11043 ([UP][RUNNING][LOWER_UP])
```

The ssid is shown my smart phone, but can't access to this ssid.
The hostapd.conf is as follow.

```
/ # cat etc/hostapd-test.conf

    interface=ra0
    hw_mode=g
    channel=10
    ssid=test
    bridge=br0
    driver=nl80211
```

And contents of ifconfig, iwconfig.

```
    / # ifconfig -a
    br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 7C:DD:90:00:00:00
              BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
              RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

    lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
              LOOPBACK  MTU:16436  Metric:1
              RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
              RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

    ra0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 7C:DD:90:00:00:00
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
              RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)


    / # iwconfig
    lo        no wireless extensions.

    ra0       IEEE 802.11bgn  Mode:Master  Frequency:2.457 GHz
              Power Management:on

    br0       no wireless extensions.
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, but the first things I'd do is (1) find out why it wants to add a monitor interface, and disable that - it's not working in the first place, (2) use a configuration without a bridge to eliminate complexity, (3) use `iw station dump` etc. (`iwconfig` is the old utility) to verify your smartphone is associated. Your smartphone may also expect protocols like DHCP to work before you can "access the SSID"; it's simpler to test with another Linux system where you can configure static IPs.

Comment: Your smartphone expects DHCP and DNS services, and in fact most modern phones, namely Apple, won´t lit up the wifi icon without having DNS and Internet access.

Comment: Thanks all. Then, should I install DNS server in my embedded board?